# Error running command oninit -i for Informix on Ubuntu Server

Tags: informix, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-server

When I call `oninit -i` command in an Ubuntu server terminal, it shows an error like this:

```
 INFORMIXSERVER does not match DBSERVERNAME or any of the DBSERVERALIASES.FAILED
```

Can anyone give me a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the setting of `$INFORMIXSERVER` in your environment, and what values are set for `DBSERVERNAME` and `DBSERVERALIASES` in the `$ONCONFIG` file?  It seems that you've set `$INFORMIXSERVER` to a value that isn't present in the `$ONCONFIG` file that is in use.  Maybe you didn't set `$ONCONFIG` at all, or maybe you set `$INFORMIXSERVER` incorrectly, or maybe the names in the `$ONCONFIG` file are incorrect.

If you don't set `$ONCONFIG`, it defaults to `onconfig` (and maybe even falls back to onconfig.std).  But you should normally set `$ONCONFIG` to a known value.  I usually use `onconfig.<servername>` where the `<servername>` is the value of `DBSERVERNAME` in the file.  However, nothing enforces that convention.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, following are my onconfig and sqlhosts files.https://gist.github.com/cdwijayarathna/22bb5a26e59b2267e824, https://gist.github.com/cdwijayarathna/e04b24011a9527256f88, I have set following environment variables as well, export INFORMIXDIR=/usr/informix
export INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=/usr/informix/etc/sqlhosts
export ONCONFIG=onconfig
export INFORMIXSERVER=myserver
export SERVERNUM=1
export PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/bin:.:$PATH, Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0606bombardier/ is a good tutorial for setting up informix DB, I came up with same issue since my rootdbs file was owned by 'root', not by 'informix', make sure all file that are mentioned in the above tutorial to be owned by user 'informix' are correctly owned.